# Angular Material Tree - TreeControl selection model doesn't work for immutable data

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx

I needed a dynamically loading nodes in the angular material tree, so I created my own `GeoDataSource` which internally uses ***@ngrx/component-store*** to handle all the interaction between data source, TreeControl and the tree itself.

Now, the problem is the tree doesn't keep its expansion state because the `abstract class BaseTreeControl<T, K = T>` uses `SelectionModel<T>` class and this in turn uses `Set<T>` to keep track of items that are selected. So if node is expanded it just does this:

```
this._selection.add(value); // Set<T>.add(value)
```

When using immutable data (from the component store) those items are always new.

I tried to use `trackBy` optional function:

```
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<SomeEntityFlatNode, string>(
      (node) => node.nodeLevel,
      (node) => node.expandable, {
        trackBy: (node) => node.groupPath // *** groupPath is string (it's an ID) ***
      }
    );
```

and for this I had to change `FlatTreeControl<SomeEntityFlatNode>` to `FlatTreeControl<SomeEntityFlatNode, string>`, otherwise it doesn't compile. But then I got the following error in the ***template***:

> Type 'FlatTreeControl<SomeEntityFlatNode, string>' is not assignable to type 'TreeControl<SomeEntityFlatNode, SomeEntityFlatNode>'

Here's the template:

```
<mat-tree *ngIf="hasData$ | async" [dataSource]="geoDataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
</mat-tree>
```

Now what? How do I make all this work with immutable data from the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I have to use `trackBy` function for TreeControl to make it work. But there's currently a bug (at the time of writing) which doesn't allow me to do it. The patch is coming though!

Comment: could you please link the bug or add some more insight into what the bug is?

Comment: I did and the fix is already merged. It should be available with the next material release. Waiting for it to try.

Comment: @Alvipeo Can you please provide a short code snippet of the final solution? I want to track nodes by their ID but somehow it doesn't work the same way as with *ngFor, the nodes always get re-created.